# Log and print Clearpath Husky sensor data with ROS and joy node

Tags: clearpath, husky, print, sensor, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm driving Husky A200 by using a joystick with this command:

```
roslaunch clearpath_teleop example.launch
```

everything works OK, but I would like to print in the shell and also write in a text file the current used by the motors, the temperature and in particular the linear and  angular velocity.

I know that clearpath_teleop cmd_vel publishes some information, but how can I read them and save them in a text file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69544/log-and-print-clearpath-husky-sensor-data-with-ros-and-joy-node/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rosbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag) can be used to save data that is published. There is logging for [C++](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Logging) & [Python](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Logging).  I don't believe that the Husky publishes motor current and temperature.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2